# Most efficient algorithm for Two-sum problem (involving indices)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, hashtable, sigabrt

The problem statement is given an array and a given sum "T", find all the pairs of indices of the elements in the array which add up to T. Additional requirements/constraints:

- Indexing starts from 0
- The indices must be displayed with lower index first (Ex: 24, 30 instead of 30, 24)
- The indices must be displayed in ascending order (Ex: if we find (1,3), (0,2) and (5,8) the output must be (0,2) (1,3) (5,8)
- There can be duplicate elements in the array, which also have to be considered

Here's my code in C++, I used the hash-table approach using `unordered_set`:

```
void Twosum(vector <int> res, int T){
    
    int temp; int ti = -1;
    unordered_set<int> s;
    vector <int> res2 = res;                  //Just a copy of the input vector
    vector <tuple<int, int>> indices;         //Result to be output
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)res.size(); i++){
        temp = T - res[i];

        if (s.find(temp) != s.end()){
            
            while(ti < (int)res.size()){     //While loop for finding all the instances of temp in the array, 
                                             //not part of the original hash-table algorithm, something I added
                
                ti = find(res2.begin(), res2.end(), temp) - res2.begin();  
                                              //Here find() takes O(n) time which is an issue
                
                res2[ti] = lim;               //To remove that instance of temp so that new instances 
                                              //can be found in the while loop, here lim = 10^9
                
                if(i <= ti) indices.push_back(make_tuple(i, ti));
                else indices.push_back(make_tuple(ti, i)); 
            }
        }
        s.insert(res[i]);
    }
    
    if(ti == -1)
        {cout<<"-1 -1";                        //if no indices were found
         return;}
    
    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end());       //sorting since unordered_set stores elements randomly
    for(int i=0; i<(int)indices.size(); i++)
        cout<<get<0>(indices[i])<<" "<<get<1>(indices[i])<<endl;
}
```

This has multiple issues:

- firstly that while loop doesn't work as intended, instead it shows `SIGABRT` error (`free(): invalid pointer`). The `ti` index is also somehow going beyond the vector bounds, even though I have that check in the while loop.
- Secondly the `find()` function works in O(n) time, which increases the overall complexity to O(n^2), which is causing my program to timeout during execution. However that function is required since we have to output indices.
- Lastly this `unordered-set` implementation doesn't seem to work when there are many duplicate elements in the array (since sets only take unique elements), which is one of the main constraints of the problem. This makes me think we need some sort of hash function or hashmap to deal with the duplicates? I'm not sure...

All the different algorithms I've found for this on the internet have dealt with just printing the elements and not the indices, hence I've had no luck with this problem.

If any of you know an optimal algorithm for this while also satisfying the constraints and running under O(n) time, your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your algorithm cannot run in `O(n)` time. If you have an array filled up with `1`s and `T=2`, then there will be `O(n²)` pairs of indices satisfying your requirements. Hence your output size may be in `O(n²)`. As for running in less than `O(n)`, that is even harder, since a simple lookup of the element in your array requires `O(n)` operations.

Comment: @m.raynal I'm aware, that's why I'm asking if there is a better optimal algorithm for this problem which works with indices.

Comment: In theory (big O complexity), this is the same problem. In practice, you can start building a map where keys are elements, and the value is the set of indices corresponding to this element. Then you can apply the algorithm which works with the elements, and iterate over all combinations of corresponding indices. It should bring a decent speed up in practice if there are many redundancies in the array. If this is what you look for I can write an answer with this algorithm

Comment: @m.raynal Yes that might just work, and yes please your full answer would be really helpful 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo-code answering your question, using hash tables (or maps) and set. I let you translate this to cpp using adapted data structures (in this case, classic hashmaps and sets will do the job well).

Notations: we will denote `A` the array, `n` its length, and `T` the "sum".

```
// first we build a map element -> {set of indices corresponding to this element}
Let M be an empty map; // or hash map, or hash table, or dictionary
for i from 0 to n-1 do {
    Let e = A[i];
    if e is not a key of M then {
        M[e] = new_set()
    }
    M[e].add(i)
}

// Now we iterate over the elements
for each key e of M do {
    if T-e is a key of M then {
        display_combinations(M[e], M[T-e]);
    }
}

// The helper function display_combinations
function display_combinations(set1, set2) {
    for each element e1 of set1 do {
        for element e2 of set2 do {
            if e1 < e2 then {
                display "(e1, e2)";
            } else if e1 > e2 then {
                display "(e2, e1)";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As said in the comments, the complexity in the worst case of this algorithm is in `O(n²)`. A way to see that we cannot go below this complexity is that the size of the output may be in `O(n²)`, in the case where all elements of the array have the value `T/2`.

Edit: this pseudo code does not output the pairs in the order. Just store them in an array of pairs, and sort this array before displaying it. Same, I did not treat the case where a pair `(i, i)` may satisfy the requirement. You may have to consider it (just change `e1 > e2` by `e1 >= e2` in the last loop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this using maps in c++, however it doesn't work if there are many duplicates in the array. I forgot to mention this in the question itself: the problem puts a bit of emphasis on dealing with duplicates, which makes me think we need some form of hashing or hash function...

Comment: You need a map that map integers to sets. Something like `std::map <int, std::set>`.